# Default option settings in cmake

Tags: cmake

Given the following cmake:

```
option (BUILD_SERVER "Build in server configuration" OFF)
option (BUILD_TOOLS "Build external tools" ON)
if (BUILD_SERVER)
    set (BUILD_TOOLS OFF)
endif()

message (STATUS "BUILD_TOOLS : ${BUILD_TOOLS}")
```

And then using ccmake to turn BUILD_SERVER ON, THEN configure, then manually turn BUILD_TOOLS back ON then configure/generate.  I get `BUILD_TOOLS : OFF`, but in CMakeCache.txt `BUILD_TOOLS:BOOL=ON`

I have two questions.  And apologies if these seem trivial. I don't have a good grasp on how cache variables work in cmake, despite reading various explanations.

1:  My desired behavior is to turn BUILD_TOOLS OFF if BUILD_SERVER is set to ON, but then allow manual changes to it.  Is this possible?  I'm guessing it might not be since it's not like there's an `event` I can capture when BUILD_SERVER changes.

2:  Can someone explain the current behavior?  I don't understand why the cache ends up with the user-set value and the script ends up with the script-set value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain the current behavior?

Command

```
set (BUILD_TOOLS OFF)
```

sets **non-cached** variable, but `CMakeCache.txt` contains (and ccmake shows) **cached** one.

Actually, you current code is *correct* from the sence, that after setting the variable it operates with non-cached version. So, if you don't care about user-visible (cache) variable, nothing is needed to be changed.

> My desired behavior is to turn BUILD_TOOLS OFF if BUILD_SERVER is set to ON

If you want to **change** cached variable in the code, use `set(... CACHE ... FORCE)` command flow:

```
if (BUILD_SERVER)
    if(BUILD_TOOLS) # Additional check for not-showing warning message to the user.
        message("WARNING: Set BUILD_TOOLS option to OFF because BUILD_SERVER is ON")
        set (BUILD_TOOLS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    endif()
endif()
```

> ... but then allow manual changes to it.

The code above allow user to set `BUILD_TOOLS` variable to TRUE event when `BUILD_SERVER` is set to TRUE. But `BUILD_TOOLS` will be reseted on next `cmake` run.

If you want to restore value of `BUILD_TOOLS` variable when `BUILD_SERVER` becomes ON, you need to store this value. Code below uses cache entry `BUILD_TOOLS_SHADOW` for store that value. Becuase this entry is INTERNAL, it doesn't shown to the user.

```
if (BUILD_SERVER)
    if(BUILD_TOOLS) # Additional check for not-showing warning message to the user.
        message("WARNING: Set BUILD_TOOLS option to OFF because BUILD_SERVER is TRUE")
        # Forcibly clear BUILD_TOOLS variable, but store its value in shadow one.
        set (BUILD_TOOLS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
        set (BUILD_TOOLS_SHADOW ${BUILD_TOOLS} CACHE INTERNAL "")
    endif()
else()
  if(BUILD_TOOLS_SHADOW)
     # Restore BUILD_TOOLS variable from shadow copy, and remove that copy.
     set (BUILD_TOOLS ${BUILD_TOOLS_SHADOW} CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
     unset (BUILD_TOOLS_SHADOW CACHE)
  endif()
endif()
```

The code becomes more difficult to understanding, and actually it has some unexpected effects. E.g., if `BUILD_TOOLS` was ON at the time when `BUILD_SERVER` became ON, then user cannot change "shadow copy" to FALSE value. But it is so only because of your *requirements*.

But if you really want to maintain non-simple logic about options' dependency, you may look into CMake module [CMakeDependentOption](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/CMakeDependentOption.html).

Comment: Thank you.  Very helpful.  I think I'm going to avoid this scenario.  It was a build convenience thing, but based on your feedback, I think it'll be easier for everyone to leave this variable set completely manually.

Comment: Yes, the main advantage of your original code is its simplicity. And CMake provides cache/non-cache variables' visibility for support such code. Also you may look into CMake module 'CMakeDependentOption' (see updated answer).

Comment: I was using CMakeDependentOption to force some variables that needed to be set a certain way, but to "default" a variable based on a change is a little weirder...and ambiguous, maybe.